# java springBoot - How to render a html page

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-development-server

I am using spring boot to try and build my own mini website.

I have a controller

```
package hello;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {


    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

and a html file resources/templates/index which I am trying to render but I just get the text "index" rendered. How can I return the html file instead of the text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified `@RestController` which says the result should be put into the `@ResponseBody`. You would want to use `@Controller` instead and then make sure you have a template framework (Thymeleaf, etc) in the classpath. Normally with most template frameworks you have to include the `.html` on the file that is within the `templates` folder.

Comment: I know i am not supposed to say thanks but thanks it did exactly want i wanted